# Is there a way to observe superlayer?

Tags: swift, calayer, key-value-observing

I have a class inherited from CALayer. In this class I need to catch an adding to superlayer event. How can I do it?

Comment: Events are for things that the runtime does, that you might otherwise _not_ know about. But since the only way the layer can be added to a superlayer is that _you_ add it, how can you _not_ know when this occurs?

Comment: @matt, do you really think that each time I add the layer to another I must write something like anylayer.addSublayer(myLayer); myLayer.didAddToSuperlayer(anylayer) ? It is a great architectural decision, I believe...

Comment: Well, there is no built-in CALayer event that the runtime will call for you, so I would say the answer to that question is Yes, you must. I presume you tried KVO on the `superlayer` property and found it wasn't working, so what other choice is there?

Comment: Why do you need an event? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: @matt, yes, KVO does not work. Overriding is not allowed (superlayer is readonly and can not be changed, haha). Have an idea to swizzle CALayer .addSublayer(), but it is too global.

Comment: Ah, no, that would be unnecessary, since there is (in effect) a `sublayers` event. If you are content to catch when a layer acquires / changes its sublayers, rather than worrying about when a layer acquires a superlayer, your problem is solved.

Comment: @Willeke, event is conceptual term here. It means any external action which can inform my layer about adding to superlayer in momentarily.

Comment: I meant the "adding to superlayer event" from the question. I understand it's a notification, event, callback or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As formulated, the answer is: You can't. There is no event sent to a layer on the occasion when it acquires a superlayer.